# How to fix gas estimation failed error while getting random number from Provable Random DS?

Tags: oracles, randomness

I'm using Provable for getting a random number and I am using following code snippet from their github: https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/random-datasource/randomExample.sol

Here is code snippet:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.6.0;

import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract RandomExample is usingOraclize {

    uint256 constant MAX_INT_FROM_BYTE = 256;
    uint256 constant NUM_RANDOM_BYTES_REQUESTED = 7;

    event LogNewOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event generatedRandomNumber(uint256 randomNumber);

    constructor()
        public
    {
        oraclize_setProof(proofType_Ledger);
        update();
    }

    function __callback(
        bytes32 _queryId,
        string memory _result,
        bytes memory _proof
    )
        public
    {
        require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());

        if (
            oraclize_randomDS_proofVerify__returnCode(
                _queryId,
                _result,
                _proof
            ) != 0
        ) {
            /**
             * @notice  The proof verification has failed! Handle this case
             *          however you see fit.
             */
        } else {
            /**
             *
             * @notice  The proof verifiction has passed!
             *
             *          Let's convert the random bytes received from the query
             *          to a `uint256`.
             *
             *          To do so, We define the variable `ceiling`, where
             *          `ceiling - 1` is the highest `uint256` we want to get.
             *          The variable `ceiling` should never be greater than:
             *          `(MAX_INT_FROM_BYTE ^ NUM_RANDOM_BYTES_REQUESTED) - 1`.
             *
             *          By hashing the random bytes and casting them to a
             *          `uint256` we can then modulo that number by our ceiling
             *          in order to get a random number within the desired
             *          range of [0, ceiling - 1].
             *
             */
            uint256 ceiling = (MAX_INT_FROM_BYTE ** NUM_RANDOM_BYTES_REQUESTED) - 1;
            uint256 randomNumber = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_result))) % ceiling;
            emit generatedRandomNumber(randomNumber);
        }
    }

    function update()
        payable
        public
    {
        uint256 QUERY_EXECUTION_DELAY = 0;
        uint256 GAS_FOR_CALLBACK = 200000;
        oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(
            QUERY_EXECUTION_DELAY,
            NUM_RANDOM_BYTES_REQUESTED,
            GAS_FOR_CALLBACK
        );
        emit LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer...");
    }

}
```

When I deployed it via remixIDE, and hit "update" button, it says the following error message:

[image: error description]

How can I fix it to get a random number?

Also, I tried depositing some ethers to my contract address too but it failed:https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x92007536a6d66387b8593063ee774b2e542dc9d0412e7dd9f244124353ff52c7